# Problem with retransmitting stdin to a server in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, client-server, irc, ocaml-lwt

I'm trying to write an IRC inspired server along with a client capable of communicating with it as a part of my uni class. I already wrote a server with which i can successfully interact using tools such as telnet. I'm having trouble with writing a client though, specifically with sending messages  from stdin to the server. Module that i use for sending/receiving messages looks as follows:

```
let (>>=) = Lwt.bind

type t = 
  { user_input : Lwt_io.input_channel;
    server_input : Lwt_io.input_channel;
    output : Lwt_io.output_channel }

let make fd =
  { user_input = Lwt_io.stdin;
    server_input = Lwt_io.of_fd ~mode:Lwt_io.input fd;
    output = Lwt_io.of_fd ~mode:Lwt_io.output fd }

let send conn msg =
  Lwt_io.write conn.output msg >>= fun _ ->
    Lwt_io.flush conn.output
      
let receive input_ch =
 Lwt_io.read_line input_ch
 >>= fun line ->
   Lwt.return line
```

Funny enough, i know that it almost works properly thanks to some classic `print_endline` debugging techniques (I logged messages sent and received by the server). The problem is, when i type something in my terminal, it doesn't go through to the server until i press `ctrl+c`. Example session looks as follows:

1. I launch the server and successfully connect to it using the client that i wrote
2. The server asks to choose my nickname
3. In my client, i type a nick and press enter
4. The server doesn't signal receiving any messages
5. I press `ctrl+c` in my client session
6. The moment the client closes the server shows that it received all characters typed into the client before shutting it down with `ctrl+c`

Based on that i assume the message doesn't actually get sent through the socket until i press `ctrl+c` for some unknown reason.

[server responses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhsbC.png) and [corresponding client session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHgRn.png) for some more reference

I was wondering if it can somehow be caused by the way i read lines using `Lwt_io.read_line`, something about it maybe not recognizing newline characters and how to fix that (So it works as intended, that is sending typed message to the server after pressing `Enter`). Additionally here's the code responsible for the main loop of the client:

```
let rec handle_user conn () =
  let open Connection in 
  receive conn.user_input
  >>= fun msg ->
    send conn msg
  >>= handle_user conn

let rec handle_server conn () = 
  let open Connection in 
  receive conn.server_input
  >>= fun msg ->
    Lwt_io.write Lwt_io.stdout msg 
  >>= handle_server conn 

let handle_connection conn () = 
  Lwt.join [
    handle_user conn ();
    handle_server conn ()
  ]
```

`handle_connection conn ()` is launched from the main function using `Lwt_main.run` after doing some standard stuff on sockets. I feel like I have scoured half of the Internet trying to come up with a solution and yet I couldn't find anything and it completely blocks my further progress working on the project.

TL:DR
Tried: Sending a message to the server after typing it in my client session and pressing `Enter`
What i expected: Response from the server signaling that it in fact received a message along with it's content
What actually happened: The message didn't go through until closing the client with `ctrl+c` after which the server signaled receiving all messages typed so far but glued together, ignoring newline characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see (without any way to reproduce the error), the issue is that `Lwt_io.read_line` returns the line without the newline characters as documented at https://ocsigen.org/lwt/5.5.0/api/Lwt_io#VALread_line. Thus,

```ml
  receive conn.user_input
  >>= send conn
```

does not send any newlines, and the server has no way to know that the current message ended before the end of the connection.

Comment: You're right, changing the `receive` function so that it returns `Lwt.return (line ^ "\n")` fixed my problem. Thanks!